# What is the probability that the dj will play only R&B and Jazz songs alternatively?

Tags: probability

I just want to check if my answer is correct.

Every Monday morning from 0700-0800 hours, the radio disk jockey (dj) on duty
must play 8 songs on radio; the songs are pre-selected by his manager and the dj may
play any eight of them randomly.

The composition of songs selected for next Monday
follows: 5 Jazz, 2 Soul, 10 R & B and 5 Country songs.

What is the probability that, on Monday next week, the dj will play only R&B and Jazz songs alternatively.

My answer : $ \frac{{(5P4)}{(10P4)}{(2)}}{22P8} = 9.382$ x $10^{-5}$

I used permutations to order 4 songs from each music style and then multiplied it by 2 because the alternation will start with either an R&B or a Jazz song.

Their answer: $9.382$ x $10^{-4}$

My answer is very similar so I thought maybe my lecturer put a $10^{-4}$ by accident. Please try the question and tell me what you think

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, and I get the same answer that you do, not your teacher's answer.

Comment: Thank you. It's not the first time he put an incorrect answer. I'm just double checking